# Need to determine why my VPS rebooted - every few days, a sudden spike

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, apache-2.4, vps

Can anyone give some advice as to why my LAMP VPS server (running centos) reboots every few days?

Well I know why - it's because the CPU and load suddenly spikes, but what causes the spike and what can I do about it?

I log a load of stats every minute, the minute of the spike top reports this:

```
top - 12:13:02 up 1 day,  2:54,  0 users,  load average: 54.35, 14.70, 5.17
Tasks: 263 total,  59 running, 203 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  7.3%us,  1.0%sy,  0.2%ni, 91.6%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8388608k total,  6851460k used,  1537148k free,        0k buffers
Swap:  4194304k total,   788260k used,  3406044k free,  4106336k cached
```

And there are a load of these (about 50):

```
23488 ealteach  20   0  186m  46m  36m R  4.1  0.6   0:01.35 php                
23556 ealteach  20   0  186m  42m  32m R  4.1  0.5   0:01.17 php                
23557 ealteach  20   0  187m  46m  36m R  4.1  0.6   0:01.31 php                
23563 ealteach  20   0  185m  40m  30m R  4.1  0.5   0:01.06 php                
23580 ealteach  20   0  186m  46m  35m R  4.1  0.6   0:01.37 php
```

Also a load of these (about 50):

```
951 nobody    20   0 80304 5756 3120 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.44 httpd              
960 nobody    20   0 78828 4208 3052 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.36 httpd              
961 nobody    20   0 79724 5048 3120 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.39 httpd              
964 nobody    20   0 78936 4312 3116 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.38 httpd              
976 nobody    20   0 78936 4284 3120 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.37 httpd
```

netstat reports a load of these (50 or more):

```
tcp        0      0 23.88.105.45:443            141.101.105.221:27034       ESTABLISHED 23535/httpd         
tcp        0      0 23.88.105.45:443            141.101.105.221:56499       ESTABLISHED 23460/httpd         
tcp        0      0 23.88.105.45:443            141.101.105.221:51605       ESTABLISHED 23520/httpd         
tcp        0      0 23.88.105.45:443            141.101.105.221:23056       ESTABLISHED 11663/httpd         
tcp        0      0 23.88.105.45:443            141.101.105.221:29759       ESTABLISHED 19770/httpd
```

And a bunch of these (50 or more):

```
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1571882093 1038/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1571882087 23563/php           
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1571879605 1038/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1571879602 23567/php           
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1571876258 1038/mysqld         /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1571876253 23570/php
```

And MySQL reports a load of these:

```
| 14477 | ealteach_main | localhost       | ealteach_main | Sleep   | 26   |       |                  | 0.000    |
| 14478 | ealteach_main | localhost       | ealteach_main | Sleep   | 27   |       |                  | 0.000    |
| 14487 | ealteach_main | localhost       | ealteach_main | Sleep   | 23   |       |                  | 0.000    |
| 14489 | ealteach_main | localhost       | ealteach_main | Sleep   | 24   |       |                  | 0.000    |
| 14493 | ealteach_main | localhost       | ealteach_main | Sleep   | 25   |       |                  | 0.000    |
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Looks like your web site is getting busy.

Comment: all of a sudden?  A spike - I don't have that many users - could it be an attack of some kind?

Comment: Who knows? Have you bothered to look at the logs?